# How do you create a union type for a component's services?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-components

I have a component that makes a call to a service method. This component is a base component so child components are providing the service using `super()` as shown below:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(protected myService: ServiceOne | ServiceTwo | ServiceThree | any) {

  }

  register(formData) {
    let response = await this.myService.register(formData);
  }
}

export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
  constructor(protected serviceOne: ServiceOne) {
    super(serviceOne);
  }
}
```

Each service (`ServiceOne`, `ServiceTwo`, and `ServiceThree`) all extend from the same base service with a shared `register()` method.

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceOne extends BaseService {
  register(user) {
    return this.post('url', user);
  }
}

export class BaseService {
  protected post(url, data) {
    return this.http.post(url, data);
  }
}
```

All of this works just fine as long as I include `any` in `ParentComponent`. But when I remove `any` from the union type, I get:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type ‘(user => Promise<any>) | (user => Promise<any>) | (user => Promise<any>)’ has no compatible call signature.
```

Is there a clean way to do this without having to resort to `any`?

Comment: Does it work any cleaner if you use an interface type instead of a concrete type? (I didn't try it ... just asking.)

Comment: Your BaseService and ServiceOne both define a method with the same name but incompatible signatures.

Comment: @IngoBürk Whoops. I updated the method name for `BaseService` to reflect reality :)

Comment: @DeborahK I'm still getting "no compatible call signature" errors.

Comment: Do you need to call `register` with `await`? Does the error go away if you remove it?

Comment: Your description doesn't match your code. Therei s no shared register method in the base service, the register method in ServiceOne doesn't return a promise as the component expects. And the base  component constructor argument shouldn't have a union type. It should simply be of type BaseService. Or better, the component should be a BaseComponent<S extends BaseService>, and accept an S as argument.

Comment: @DeborahK Thank you for your guidance and help! I added the solution if you're curious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as [@DeborahK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647604/deborahk) suggested, an interface was the way to go.

Here's the interface and updated constructor. (Update `Promise<>` wrapper as needed).

```
interface DynamicService {
  register: (service) => (Promise<ServiceOne | ServiceTwo | ServiceThree>);
}

export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(protected myService: DynamicService) {

  }

  register(formData) {
    let response = await this.myService.register(formData);
  }
}

export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
  constructor(protected serviceOne: ServiceOne) {
    super(serviceOne);
  }
}
```